# PHP not executing INSERT INTO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-insert

My data not inserting into database, And I'm using PHP,

I have the following code that is working:

```
$VS= $Player->Db->query('Status', 0, 0, "SELECT * FROM web_status WHERE steamid LIKE '%" . con_steam32to64( $Player->get_steam_32() ) . "%' LIMIT 1" );
                    $SteamID64 = $VS['steamid'];
                    $a2= $VS['2'];
                    $a3= $VS['3'];
                    $a4= $VS['4']; 
                    $a5= $VS['5'];
                    $a6= $VS['6'];
                    $a7= $VS['7'];
                    $a8= $VS['8'];
```

Then when I want to add a new line in the table I have the following one which is not working any clue why because I made one `echo` under that line and I can see the echo.

```
$Player->Db->query('Status', 0, 0, "INSERT INTO `web_status`(`steamid`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8`) VALUES (".$NewSID.",".$NewCB.",".$NewVB.",".$NewNB.",".$NewDSLB.",".$NewNGB.",".$NewEB.",".$NewTodayDate.")" );
```

Also I have made `echo` to the following variables `.$NewSID.",".$NewCB.",".$NewVB.",".$NewNB.",".$NewDSLB.",".$NewNGB.",".$NewEB.",".$NewTodayDate.` and all of them have values.

Comment: Are you using the correct single quotes in your insert statement

Comment: What are your column names? Are they really just numbers?

Comment: What does this display: `echo "INSERT INTO `web_status`(`steamid`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8`) VALUES (".$NewSID.",".$NewCB.",".$NewVB.",".$NewNB.",".$NewDSLB.",".$NewNGB.",".$NewEB.",".$NewTodayDate.")";`

Answer (score -1):

Can you use the following way

```
$Player->Db->query('Status', 0, 0, 
  "INSERT INTO `web_status`(`steamid`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8`) 
    VALUES (
      '{$NewSID}','{$NewCB}',
      '{$NewVB}','{$NewNB}',
      '{$NewDSLB}','{$NewNGB}',
      '{$NewEB}','{$NewTodayDate}'
    )"
);
```

**NOTE:** Make sure you are passing single quotes for the string values and remove for integers or float.